# How to perform an integration test without persisting data at all?

Tags: unit-testing, abap

Is there a way to persist no data at all in a test, but just temporary until the test completes? With OSQL Test Double Framework we can replace single tables, but often APIs are used where we don't know which tables will be touched (e.g. create a transport).

E.g. imagine implementations for `ZIF_MY_BUSINESS_OBJECT` and `ZIF_MY_API`. The unit tests for the business object validate that you cannot call e.g. `send( )` before `mv_valid = abap_true` (set by `init( )`).
The unit tests of `ZIF_MY_API` use test double to replace `ZIF_MY_BUSINESS_OBJECT`. So I test assumptions like the following flow

```
METHOD ZIF_MY_API~perform_send.
   " NOTE: THIS ONLY WORKS IN PROD WHEN ->init was called before, here in ZIF_MY_API~start!!
   mo_business_obj->load_or_exception( ).
   mo_business_obj->validate_or_exception( ).
   mo_business_obj->send( ).
ENDMETHOD.
```

In the test I can just say the mock `mo_business_obj->validate( )` will throw an exception. I cannot test that a call to `ZIF_MY_API~start( )` will setup the `mo_business_obj` correctly (else I'd depend on the implementation of mo_business_obj).

So I see no other way to write an full integration test for

```
ZIF_MY_API~start( )
ZIF_MY_API~perform_send( )
Excpect: NO ERROR
```

```
ZIF_MY_API~perform_send( )
Excpect: ERROR
```

But this will persist all kind of data, which I don't need in my system. So back to the original question: My unit tests test the code itself, not how they integrate. The lowest level will mock out the persistency. But as soon as I want to test the interaction, data will be persisted.

1. Is there a way to instruct the OSQL Test Double Framework to redirect every OSQL in the session
2. Would it be better to write an integration test where I inject a persistency interface instead? So everything is production code, except the wrapper interface of the persistency?

Comment: 1: No. 2: Yes, but not with unit testing, you usually do it by test scripts (robots, etc.) it's a job done by integration testers. If you want and if you can, you may write the script in ABAP, but not with ABAP Unit. NB: you say it all: "My unit tests test the code itself, not how they integrate". Yes, it's how it should be. It seems that you want to cross the doorstep of integration tests. You shouldn't... OSQL Test Double Framework is only intended to be used in unit testing.

Comment: A couple years ago I asked a very similar question during a presentation from SAP about test doubles: "What am I supposed to do when I use an API I don't know (like a BAPI) and want to make sure I mock all the database tables it could possibly write? Is there some catch-all setting?". The answer by the SAP employee holding the presentation was basically "No, there isn't. Run the BAPI in a database trace and find out what tables you need to mock".

Comment: @Philipp In my case I'd then rather put that BAPI in my own custom local interface and swap the whole thing out so it does nothing when I run my test. Funnily enough I also now found resources that the sql mock is too heavy for common usage. Well

Comment: @Regyn well, if the thing you want to test is if you call the BAPI in the correct way, then that does not help.